# Angular 2 how to use Applets

Tags: html, angular

I have currently a problem with embeding my Applet .jar file into my Angular 2 Project.

Most of the solution mention using the `<applet></applet>` tag but I get the following error when i try it:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

'applet' is not a known element:
1. If 'applet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'applet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you know that applets are no longer supported by several browsers? Chrome for example...

Comment: yes, i do know that but my projekt requires to include that applet

Answer (score 0):

Ok, HTML5 replaced `<applet></applet>` with `<object></object>`.
Tried it and now it works

Comment: I have a similar requirement to use applet. do you have implementation example for reference ?